# Why does an empty Django queryset truthy value not equal None?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have an empty queryset type `Foo` which I expected to be None returning `False` when checked. Here is what my code looks like:

```py
>>> queryset = Foo.objects.all()
>>> queryset
<FooQuerySet []>
>>> queryset is None
False
```

I'd hoped for `True` since its an actual empty queryset.

Comment: That's not really truthyness, is it? Truthyness would be if you evaluated `bool(queryset)`. Also, Django can't override the `is` operator.

Comment: It is not `None` because it is not `None`. If you want to check the truthiness, a simple `if queryset:` might be an option.

Answer (score -1):

So **is** returns True if x and y points to the same memory address, so it require variables to store **THE SAME OBJECT**, while **==** check if the objects reffered by variables are equal.

```py
x = 10
y = x
x is y # True
x == y # True
a = 100
b = 10 * 10
a is b # False
a == b # True
```

Comment: Python doesn't promise that this code will produce the output you say it does. In practice, it doesn't - `a is b` will be True due to small int caching - but Python doesn't promise that either.

Comment: Also, replacing `is` with `==` in the question's code won't make the comparison report `True` either.

Comment: Lol to be honest I wasn’t aware of this, and for your second comment I know but with brief introduction what both mean op should be able to resolve that what he tried to do makes no sense